# Provision windows machine with vagrant to install github desktop

Tags: github, vagrant, provisioning, chocolatey

I try to install github desktop via chocolatey (vagrant provisioning) on my windows virtual machine. The installation process runs until the actual github installation. The error message looks like this:

> Download of GitHubSetup.exe (663.49 KB) completed
>
> WARNING: Ignoring checksums due to feature checksumFiles turned off or option --ignore-checksums set.
>
> Installing github...
>
> github has been installed.
>
> Microsoft's ClickOnce framework is downloading and extracting the ~110
> MB install files.
>
> This may take several minutes or longer. Please wait...

The installation hangs at this point. I read about this issue at the official chocolatey [webpage](https://chocolatey.org/packages/GitHub#comment-2295508881) . How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: the installation works when executed during VM runtime in a ps console

Comment: Newest vagrant has some fixes in 1.9.2 that may affect this for the better.

Comment: this does not change the issue

Comment: Just thought of this - are you specifying interactive in the shell options? Here is an example - https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-test-environment/blob/10a32f63cc4ed4ef14251ceadf5253e358ec32f7/Vagrantfile#L120

Comment: this helps to install github, but the provisioning script does not finish after installation. the provisioning says: 
==> default: github has been installed.

==> default:   Microsoft's ClickOnce framework is downloading and extracting the ~110 MB install files.

==> default:   This may take several minutes or longer. Please wait...


but does not finish

Comment: Just a note - if you look at the Chocolatey community package page for this package - https://chocolatey.org/packages/github, there may be a red dot up by the name. If you click on that it will show you the verifier's failing tests. It runs vagrant - it has had the same issue you are running into in the past. If you are able to figure out why it is failing, I would share that with the package maintainers so they can get that fixed. HTH